# Question on a Collatz-like problem

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

For a positive integer $n$ define $f(n)$ as:
\begin{equation}
f(n) = 
\begin{cases}        n/2, & \text{if $n$ is even}\\
        n + \lfloor n^x \rfloor, & \text{if $n$ is odd.}
\end{cases}\end{equation}
I want to know for what values of $x$ we can repeat this two operations until this function returns $1$. Also, if it's possible to offer some explanation or proof of why this happens.

For $0<n< 10^5$ I've found the following values of $x$ that return $1$.
$$x \in \{
0.26 , 0.37, 0.39, 0.4 , 0.43, 0.44 , 0.45, 0.5, 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54\}$$

Code in python:

```
import math as math
x = 0.5 # choose a x to test
def function(n):
  while(n!=1):
        if(n%2 == 0): n = n/2
        else: n = n + math.floor(math.pow(n, x))
        print(n) # print each step to make sure it is correct
         
number=1 
while(number < 100000): # test the first 10^5 positive integers
       function(number)
       number = number + 1
       print("number = ", number) 
     #  if the integer tested is printed, this means it reached 1,
     #  if not, it entered an infinite loop never reaching 1
     #  (to be sure you can print 'n' (the steps) inside the first while loop)
```

You can paste this in
https://www.online-python.com, or go directly to https://www.online-python.com/ofrZdkGNCO; or use another online Python compilers.

Example:
For $n=50301$ and $x=0.5$ we have the steps:

```
50525
50749
50974
25487
25646 
12823 
12936
6468
3234
1617
1657
1697
1738
869
898
449
470
235
250
125
136
68
34
17
21
25
30
15
18
9
12
6
3
4
2
1
```

Comment: I am confused by your quantification.  Is your set of $x$s those for which, for every $n$ in your specified test range, there is some positive integer $m$ such that $f_x^m(n)$ equals $1$?  I would be suspicious of the accuracy of your code without using some sort of `BigInt` library, but I'm not a Pythonista.  (Maybe `math` does it already?) \\ TeX note: there is an environment `{cases}` that is meant exactly for the sort of piecewise definition you gave.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: It's just like the collatz conjecture. If you choose an $x$ in that set, say, $x=0.37$, then for every positive integer less than $10^5$ that you choose, after some number of interactions, $f(n)$ will be equal to 1. Not sure if this is what your are asking.

Comment: Hmm... maybe would be useful to print the 'steps' for each integer tested. to test the corrects of the code.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice your $x$s were decimals. Then all the more I would be suspicious of rounding errors.

Comment: Why people are voting to close this question?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455211/question-on-a-collatz-like-problem#comment1178564_455211), it seems like a potentially interesting question, but there is an infinite, possibly uncountable, family of variations of Collatz that one could ask.  Without some motivation for why this is particularly interesting, or a particular research angle, such questions tend to be closed.

Comment: @LSpice I didn't know there is several functions lile this one. I'm trying to find papers about other functions/collatz like problems like this one but I'm not succeding. I tried googling "collatz like problems/functions" but couldn't find a function similar to this one or the $3n+1$. Do you know how/where I can find variations of collatz problems/functions? Maybe papers that offer some insight on how to create such functions and examples.

Comment: @LSpice doesn't need to be papers exaclty, anything already helps.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1178613), this is not my research area, so I couldn't point to any specific reference; as I say, there are at least infinitely many possible variants of Collatz, so, for all I know, your specific variant is new (but it could equally well have been studied already; I just don't know).  Here are my first two thoughts for where to look: [MathSciNet search for `any:"Collatz-like"`](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/publications-search?query=any%3A%22Collatz-like%22); [Tao's posts on Collatz](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/collatz-conjecture).

Comment: @Pinteco If you'd like to know some other Collatz-like problems, pick your choice of any function $f(x)=ax+1$ if $x$ is odd and $x/2$ if $x$ is even, where $a$ is any odd number of your choosing. Then interate. There you go, a list of infinitely many such Collatz-like problems to get you started.

Comment: @it'sahirecarbaby this algorithm will not return 1 if a!=3. Tell me a function which will always return 1.